# Quantifier {n,m} The preceding item is matched at least n times, but not more than m times not working in R

Tags: regex, r

My code is

```
strings <- c("a","aa","aaa", "aaaa-EA","aaaaaa-EA")
pattern = "a{2,4}-EA$"
grepl(pattern,strings,perl=TRUE)
```

Output is: `FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE`

Ideally, I should get `FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `^` to indicate the start of the string:

```
> pattern <- "^a{2,4}-EA$"
> grepl(pattern, strings)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Otherwise the pattern matching is independent of position.

Answer (score 1):

As Sven pointed out, the string with 5 a's has a substring with 4 a's that can get matched when you don't specify the start of the string.

Alternatively, you can use a negative look behind assertion to ensure you only match a maximum of 4:

```
grepl("(?<!a)a{2,4}-EA$",strings,perl=TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: I tried using your approach, but with a positive lookahead for "-EA" if 4 "a's" are found.  grepl("a{2,4}(?= -EA)",strings,perl=TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE.  What is my mistake?

Comment: @lawyeR A space between the `=` and the `-`

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaargh   Why can't either computers be more compassionate and thoughtful or me be more careful!!  Thank you